# How can i end an if statement and break out of all others?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, blackjack

I am making a black jack program for a class, and i have a series of "if loops"my issue is thatwhen i say yes, hit me with another card, it proceeds to the next step as i would like, but when i say "no, i am holding", it still asks me if i would like to hit again. How can i make it so that when i say no, I then end the function completly? program is below.

```
 players=input('Welcome to Matjack! Aces count as 11, and face cards count as 10. Please enter the number of players:')

if players==1;
    card_1=randi(11,1);
    card_2=randi(11,1);
    fprintf ('Face up card is %d! Face down is unknown!',card_1)
    hit=input(' Hit? Y/N:','s')
    if hit=='Y';
        card_3=randi(11,1);
        cards=card_1+card_3;
        player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3;
        if player_1<21;
            fprintf('Value of face up cards is %d. Face down is still unknown!',cards);
            hit=input(' Hit again? Y/N:','s')
            if hit=='Y';
                card_4=randi(11,1);
                cards=card_1+card_3+card_4;
                player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4;
            end
             if player_1>21 ;
            fprintf ('Player one broke! Total card value was %d',player_1)
             end

             if hit=='N';
                 player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3;
                 fprintf ('Player one holds! Total card value was %d',player_1)
             end
        end
        if player_1<21
            fprintf('Value of face up cards is %d. Face down is still unknown!',cards);      
            hit=input(' Hit again? Y/N:','s')
            if hit=='Y';
                card_5=randi(11,1);
                cards=card_1+card_3+card_4+card_5;
                player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4+card_5;
            end
             if player_1>21 ;
            fprintf ('Player one broke! Total card value was %d',player_1)
        end
             if hit=='N';
        player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4;
        fprintf ('Player one holds! Total card value was %d',player_1)
        end

        end
        if player_1<21
            fprintf('Value of face up cards is %d. Face down is still unknown!',cards);      
            hit=input(' Hit again? Y/N:','s')
            if hit=='Y';
                card_6=randi(11,1);
                cards=card_1+card_3+card_4+card_5+card_6;
                player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4+card_5+card_6;
            end
             if player_1>21 ;
            fprintf ('Player one broke! Total card value was %d',player_1)
        end
             if hit=='N';
        player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4+card_5;
        fprintf ('Player one holds! Total card value was %d',player_1)
        end
        end
    if player_1<21
            fprintf('Value of face up cards is %d. Face down is still unknown!',cards);      
            hit=input(' Hit again? Y/N:','s')
            if hit=='Y';
                card_7=randi(11,1);
                cards=card_1+card_3+card_4+card_5+card_6+card_7;
                player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4+card_5+card_6+card_7;
            end
             if player_1>21 ;
            fprintf ('Player one broke! Total card value was %d',player_1)
        end
             if hit=='N';
        player_1=card_1+card_2+card_3+card_4+card_5+card_6;
        fprintf ('Player one holds! Total card value was %d',player_1)
             end
    end
    end

    if hit=='N';
        player_1=card_1+card_2;
        fprintf ('Player one holds! Total card value was %d',player_1)
    end

     end
```

Comment: Maybe use `return`? Just a comment also: don't use `==` to compare 2 strings like `hit` and `Y`. Rather use [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to compare the whole string and not individual letters.

Comment: You should rewrite the card-dealing part of the program to use a loop and a vector of card values instead of copy+pasting the same code over and over. As it is your program can only support 7 cards, but what if the player wanted more than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it a bit. Some functions you might want to add are the split, put in suits, and add in persistent player names. I tried to put in descriptive variable and function names.

```
function Matjack
global AllCards decks
AllCards = [];
clc

DealerHitOnSoft17 = 1;

disp('Welcome to Matjack! Aces count as 11, and face cards count as 10.')

if DealerHitOnSoft17
    disp('Dealer hits on soft 17')
else
    disp('Dealer holds on soft 17')
end

NumberPlayers = input('Please enter the number of players:');
decks = input('How many decks of cards do you want to play with? ');

playerName = cellfun(@(n) strjoin({'Player ', num2str(n)}, ' '), num2cell((1:NumberPlayers)'), 'uni', 0);

dealerCards = DealCards(2, []);

if Blackjack('Dealer', dealerCards)
    printHand('Dealer''s', dealerCards)
    disp('You lose')
    return
end

printHand('Dealer''s', dealerCards(1))

playerHands = cellfun(@(n) DealCards(n, []), num2cell(2 * ones( NumberPlayers, 1)), 'uni', 0);
isPlaying = ones(size(playerHands));

for i = 1:NumberPlayers
    isPlaying(i) = ~Blackjack(['Player ', num2str(i)], playerHands{i});
end

    while any(isPlaying)
        for i = 1:NumberPlayers
            if isPlaying(i)
                printHand(playerName{i}, playerHands{i})

                if strcmpi(input([playerName{i}, ' has ', num2str(sumHand(playerHands{i}, 0)),'. Hit? Y/N:'],'s'), 'y')
                    playerHands{i} = DealCards(1, playerHands{i});
                    printHand(playerName{i}, playerHands{i})
                    disp([playerName{i}, ' has ', num2str(sumHand(playerHands{i}, 0)),'.'])

                    if sumHand(playerHands{i}, 0) > 21
                        disp([playerName{i}, ' busts!'])
                        isPlaying(i) = 0;
                    end
                else
                    disp([playerName{i}, ' holds at ', num2str(sumHand(playerHands{i}, 0)),'.'])
                    isPlaying(i) = 0;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    printHand('Dealer''s', dealerCards)

    while sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17) < 17
        dealerCards = DealCards(1, dealerCards);
        printHand('Dealer', dealerCards)

        if sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17) > 21
            disp('Dealer busts!')
        elseif sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17) > 17
            disp(['Dealer holds at ', num2str(sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17)),'.'])
        else
            disp(['Dealer has ', num2str(sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17)),'.'])
        end

    end

    cellfun(@(name, h) WinDrawLose(name, sumHand(h, 0), sumHand(dealerCards, DealerHitOnSoft17)), playerName, playerHands);    

end

function hand = DealCards(N, hand)
    global AllCards decks
    possibleCards = randi(52 * decks, N, 1);

    [C, ia, ~] = unique([AllCards; possibleCards], 'stable');
    ia = ia - length(AllCards);
    ia(ia < 1) = [];

    n = length(AllCards) + N - length(C);
    AllCards = C;
    hand = [hand; possibleCards(ia)];

    if n > 0
        hand = DealCards(n, hand);
    end
end

function printHand(player, hand)
    ord = horzcat('Ace', cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(2:10), 'uni', 0), 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King');
    hand = mod(hand - 1, 13) + 1;

    if length(hand) == 1
        disp([player, ' face up card is ', strjoin(ord(hand), ', '), '. Face down is unknown!'])
    elseif length(hand) > 1
        disp([player, ' cards are ', strjoin(ord(hand), ', '), '.'])
    end
end

function S = sumHand(hand, dealerSoft)
    hand = mod(hand - 1, 13) + 1;
    hand(hand >= 10) = 10;
    hand(hand == 1 ) =  11;

    S = sum(hand);

    while ((S > 21) && any(hand == 11))
        if ~(dealerSoft && ((17 <= S) && (S <= 21)))
            n = find(hand == 11, 1, 'first');
            hand(n) = 1;
            S = sum(hand);
        end
    end
end

function bj = Blackjack(player, hand)
    if (length(hand) == 2) && (sumHand(hand, 0) == 21)
        bj = 1;
        disp([player, ' hit blackjack!'])
    else
        bj = 0;
    end
end

function WinDrawLose(name, player, dealer)
    if ((player < dealer) && (dealer <= 21)) || (player > 21)
        disp([name, ' loses.'])
    elseif (player == dealer)
        disp([name, ' draws.'])
    else
        disp([name, ' wins.'])
    end
end
```

Comment: What functions did you add?